# XML Reader to get all elements and child nodes between specific tags

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I am needing to read between specific tags within a XML document. The issue I am having is that not every XML is the same. If the XML contains multiple images, a for each loop is needed but that tag name is FilingConnectedDocument while a single image XML starting tag is FilingLeadDocument. The information I am needing from the XML is the nc:DocumentReceivedDate, nc:DocumentDescriptionText and RegisterActionDescriptionText. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

C# code using XML Reader:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sourceDir2 = @"server file path";

        XmlReaderSettings settings2 = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings2.IgnoreComments = true;
        settings2.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
        settings2.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        settings2.CheckCharacters = false;

        // Reads only XML files from the specific folder
        string[] fileEntries2 = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir2, "*.xml");

        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries2)
        {
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, settings2);

            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

XML Format:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<RecordFilingRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:wsdl:WebServiceMessagingProfile-Definitions-4.0">
  <RecordFilingRequestMessage xmlns:fsrsp="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:FilingStatusResponseMessage-4.0" xmlns:ecf="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0" xmlns:j="http://niem.gov/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0" xmlns:juvenile="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:JuvenileCase-4.0" xmlns:niem-xsd="http://niem.gov/niem/proxy/xsd/2.0" xmlns:domestic="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:DomesticCase-4.0" xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:criminal="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CriminalCase-4.0" xmlns:amcadext="http://www.amcad.com/NiemEcf/extensions/1.0" xmlns:i="http://niem.gov/niem/appinfo/2.0" xmlns:appellate="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:AppellateCase-4.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:citation="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CitationCase-4.0" xmlns:reviewcb="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:ReviewFilingCallbackMessage-4.0" xmlns:civil="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CivilCase-4.0">
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="ReviewWorkQueueId">476</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="ReviewWorkQueue">Circuit Criminal Existing Cases</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:IdentificationID>6379325</nc:IdentificationID>
    </nc:DocumentIdentification>
    <nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:56:14.290623-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentPostDate>
    <nc:DocumentSubmitter>
      <ecf:EntityPerson s:id="REVIEWER">
        <nc:PersonName>
          <nc:PersonGivenName></nc:PersonGivenName>
          <nc:PersonSurName></nc:PersonSurName>
          <nc:PersonFullName></nc:PersonFullName>
        </nc:PersonName>
        <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>27404</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
        <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID></nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_LOGONNAME</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
        <ecf:PersonAugmentation>
          <nc:ContactInformation>
            <nc:ContactEmailID></nc:ContactEmailID>
          </nc:ContactInformation>
        </ecf:PersonAugmentation>
      </ecf:EntityPerson>
    </nc:DocumentSubmitter>
    <ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <nc:IdentificationID>Filing Review MDE</nc:IdentificationID>
    </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
    <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
    <CoreFilingMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CoreFilingMessage-4.0">
      <nc:DocumentEffectiveDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentEffectiveDate>
      <nc:DocumentIdentification>
        <nc:IdentificationID>6379325</nc:IdentificationID>
      </nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:DocumentInformationCutOffDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentInformationCutOffDate>
      <nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
      <nc:DocumentSubmitter>
        <ecf:EntityPerson s:id="FILER">
          <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName></nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonSurName></nc:PersonSurName>
            <nc:PersonNameSuffixText s:metadata="III">III</nc:PersonNameSuffixText>
            <nc:PersonFullName></nc:PersonFullName>
          </nc:PersonName>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID>24759</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID>STB</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_LOGONNAME</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID>128820FL</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>BAR_NUMBER</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID></nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>EMPLOYER</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <ecf:PersonAugmentation>
            <nc:ContactInformation>
              <nc:ContactEmailID></nc:ContactEmailID>
              <nc:ContactMailingAddress>
                <nc:StructuredAddress>
                  <nc:AddressDeliveryPointText></nc:AddressDeliveryPointText>
                  <nc:LocationCityName></nc:LocationCityName>
                  <nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>FL</nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                  <nc:LocationStateName></nc:LocationStateName>
                  <nc:LocationPostalCode></nc:LocationPostalCode>
                </nc:StructuredAddress>
                <nc:AddressFullText></nc:AddressFullText>
              </nc:ContactMailingAddress>
              <nc:ContactTelephoneNumber s:id="PRIMARYPHONE">
                <nc:FullTelephoneNumber>
                  <nc:TelephoneNumberFullID></nc:TelephoneNumberFullID>
                </nc:FullTelephoneNumber>
              </nc:ContactTelephoneNumber>
            </nc:ContactInformation>
          </ecf:PersonAugmentation>
        </ecf:EntityPerson>
      </nc:DocumentSubmitter>
      <ecf:SendingMDELocationID s:id="Filing Assembly MDE">
        <nc:IdentificationID>http://www.myflcourtaccess.com/Courts/UIPages/SimpleEFileFees.aspx?organizationId=5</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationID>209.16.117.2</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
      </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
      <ecf:ElectronicServiceInformation s:id="1">
        <ecf:ServiceRecipientID s:id="24759" s:metadata="Samuel Bookhardt III">
          <nc:IdentificationID>;</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>Electronic</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </ecf:ServiceRecipientID>
      </ecf:ElectronicServiceInformation>
      <ecf:ElectronicServiceInformation s:id="2">
        <ecf:ServiceRecipientID s:id="-1" s:metadata="Phil Archer, State Attorney">
          <nc:IdentificationID>;;</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>Electronic</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </ecf:ServiceRecipientID>
      </ecf:ElectronicServiceInformation>
      <criminal:Case>
        <nc:ActivityDescriptionText s:id="Circuit Criminal">Other Crimes Against Persons</nc:ActivityDescriptionText>
        <nc:ActivityStatus>
          <nc:StatusText>ORIGINAL PEND                           </nc:StatusText>
          <nc:StatusDate>
            <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T00:00:00-04:00</nc:DateTime>
          </nc:StatusDate>
        </nc:ActivityStatus>
        <nc:CaseTitleText></nc:CaseTitleText>
        <nc:CaseCategoryText s:id="40781916530">904</nc:CaseCategoryText>
        <nc:CaseTrackingID></nc:CaseTrackingID>
        <nc:CaseTrackingID s:id="ucn"></nc:CaseTrackingID>
        <j:CaseAugmentation>
          <j:CaseCourt>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>5</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>2</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION_UNIT</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>Trial</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>COURT_TYPE</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>Eighteenth Circuit</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>JUDICIAL_CIRCUIT_ID</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationName></nc:OrganizationName>
            <nc:OrganizationUnitName>Circuit </nc:OrganizationUnitName>
            <j:CourtName></j:CourtName>
          </j:CaseCourt>
        </j:CaseAugmentation>
        <ecf:CaseAugmentation>
          <nc:LanguageCode xsi:nil="true" />
        </ecf:CaseAugmentation>
      </criminal:Case>
      <FilingConfidentialityIndicator>false</FilingConfidentialityIndicator>
      <FilingLeadDocument s:id="DOC00001" s:metadata="# Pages=3">
        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="Motions">Motion to Set Bond</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="FileInputId">101</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6PublicAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6ConfidentialAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="TypeOfConfidentialDocument">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
          <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="2089067143">3022      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
          <ecf:FilingPartyID>
            <nc:IdentificationID>24759</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </ecf:FilingPartyID>
          <ecf:SpecialHandlingInstructions />
        </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
            <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
            <nc:DocumentFileControlID>bond jeremey carmichael.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
            <ecf:DocumentAttachment s:id="ATT00001">
              <nc:BinaryBase64Object></nc:BinaryBase64Object>
              <nc:BinarySizeValue>12862</nc:BinarySizeValue>
              <ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>1</ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>
            </ecf:DocumentAttachment>
          </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </FilingLeadDocument>
      <FilingConnectedDocument s:id="DOC00002" s:metadata="# Pages=1">
        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="Notices">Notice of Hearing</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="FileInputId">102</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6PublicAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6ConfidentialAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="TypeOfConfidentialDocument">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>2</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
          <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="2089067191">6724      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
          <ecf:FilingPartyID>
            <nc:IdentificationID>24759</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </ecf:FilingPartyID>
        </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
            <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
            <nc:DocumentFileControlID>NOH Bond Nebbia 10.11.13.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
            <ecf:DocumentAttachment s:id="ATT00002">
              <nc:BinaryBase64Object></nc:BinaryBase64Object>
              <nc:BinarySizeValue>8812</nc:BinarySizeValue>
              <ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>2</ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>
            </ecf:DocumentAttachment>
          </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </FilingConnectedDocument>
    </CoreFilingMessage>
    <RecordDocketingMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:RecordDocketingMessage-4.0">
      <nc:DocumentIdentification>
        <nc:IdentificationID>6379325</nc:IdentificationID>
      </nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:56:14.290623-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DocumentSubmitter>
        <ecf:EntityPerson s:id="REVIEWER">
          <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName></nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonSurName></nc:PersonSurName>
            <nc:PersonFullName></nc:PersonFullName>
          </nc:PersonName>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID>27404</nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
            <nc:IdentificationID></nc:IdentificationID>
            <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_LOGONNAME</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
          </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <ecf:PersonAugmentation>
            <nc:ContactInformation>
              <nc:ContactEmailID></nc:ContactEmailID>
            </nc:ContactInformation>
          </ecf:PersonAugmentation>
        </ecf:EntityPerson>
      </nc:DocumentSubmitter>
      <ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
        <nc:IdentificationID>Filing Review MDE</nc:IdentificationID>
      </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
      <j:CaseCourt>
        <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>5</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
        <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>2</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION_UNIT</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
        <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>Trial</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>COURT_TYPE</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
        <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>Eighteenth Circuit</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>JUDICIAL_CIRCUIT_ID</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
        <nc:OrganizationName>Brevard</nc:OrganizationName>
        <nc:OrganizationUnitName>Circuit Criminal</nc:OrganizationUnitName>
        <j:CourtName>Brevard Circuit Criminal</j:CourtName>
      </j:CaseCourt>
      <nc:CaseTrackingID>052013CF050219AXXXXX</nc:CaseTrackingID>
      <ecf:ReviewedLeadDocument s:id="REVIEWEDDOC00001">
        <nc:DocumentFiledDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T00:00:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentFiledDate>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <nc:DocumentStatus>
          <nc:StatusText>ACCEPTED</nc:StatusText>
        </nc:DocumentStatus>
        <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
          <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="2089067143">3022      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
          <ecf:ParentDocumentReference s:ref="DOC00001" />
        </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata s:metadata="3" />
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </ecf:ReviewedLeadDocument>
      <ecf:ReviewedConnectedDocument s:id="REVIEWEDDOC00002">
        <nc:DocumentFiledDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T00:00:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentFiledDate>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2013-10-14T16:11:45.677</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>2</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <nc:DocumentStatus>
          <nc:StatusText>ACCEPTED</nc:StatusText>
        </nc:DocumentStatus>
        <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
          <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="2089067191">6724      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
          <ecf:ParentDocumentReference s:ref="DOC00002" />
        </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata s:metadata="1" />
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </ecf:ReviewedConnectedDocument>
    </RecordDocketingMessage>
    <payment:PaymentMessage xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-1.0" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-1.0" xmlns:receipt="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:PaymentReceiptMessage-4.0" xmlns:payment="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:PaymentMessage-4.0">
      <payment:PayerName></payment:PayerName>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:ID identificationSchemeID="NA" identificationSchemeName="Filing fee" identificationSchemeAgencyID="-1">NA</cac:ID>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:PrepaidIndicator>false</cbc:PrepaidIndicator>
        <cbc:SequenceNumeric>1</cbc:SequenceNumeric>
        <cbc:Amount amountCurrencyID="USD">0</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:Reason>Filing fee</cac:Reason>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:ID identificationSchemeID="NA" identificationSchemeName="Motions Motion to Set Bond" identificationSchemeAgencyID="101">NA</cac:ID>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:PrepaidIndicator>false</cbc:PrepaidIndicator>
        <cbc:SequenceNumeric>2</cbc:SequenceNumeric>
        <cbc:Amount amountCurrencyID="USD">0</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:Reason>Motions Motion to Set Bond</cac:Reason>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
      <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:ID identificationSchemeID="NA" identificationSchemeName="Notices Notice of Hearing" identificationSchemeAgencyID="102">NA</cac:ID>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>true</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:PrepaidIndicator>false</cbc:PrepaidIndicator>
        <cbc:SequenceNumeric>3</cbc:SequenceNumeric>
        <cbc:Amount amountCurrencyID="USD">0</cbc:Amount>
        <cac:Reason>Notices Notice of Hearing</cac:Reason>
      </cac:AllowanceCharge>
      <cac:Address>
        <cac:AddressLine>
          <cbc:Line>1980 Michigan Ave.</cbc:Line>
          <cbc:Line />
          <cbc:Line>Cocoa</cbc:Line>
          <cbc:Line>FL</cbc:Line>
          <cbc:Line>32922</cbc:Line>
        </cac:AddressLine>
      </cac:Address>
    </payment:PaymentMessage>
  </RecordFilingRequestMessage>
</RecordFilingRequest>
```

Comment: you are not showing the header of xml.!

Comment: Are you certain you want to use XmlReader and not LINQ to XML?

Comment: @galenus I know very little about LINQ to XML. I have seen the examples through online research but that is about it. The element tag "<CoreFilingMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CoreFilingMessage-4.0">" contains the information I am needing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this like,

```
            string xmlFile = File.ReadAllText(@"Yourxml.xml");
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlFile);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("FilingLeadDocument");
            List<info> inforamtion = new List<info>();
            foreach (XmlElement node in nodeList)
            {
                info inf=new info();
                inf.RegisterActionDescriptionText = node.GetElementsByTagName("j:RegisterActionDescriptionText")[0].InnerText;
                inf.DocumentDescriptionText = node.GetElementsByTagName("nc:DocumentDescriptionText")[0].InnerText;
                inf.DocumentReceivedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(node.GetElementsByTagName("nc:DocumentReceivedDate")[0].FirstChild.InnerText);
                inforamtion.Add(inf);
            }


   class info
    {
       internal string RegisterActionDescriptionText { get; set; }
       internal string DocumentDescriptionText { get; set; }
       internal DateTime DocumentReceivedDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: with the string xmlFile, I can use my source that contains the multiple XML files I am needing to read correct?

Comment: Yes. Yourxml.xml will be the source file that contains your entire xml data here. you can change the way as you like. @clerktech

Comment: I have never used "info" in my applications before. How would I view the output of the XML from those specific elements. I would like to put them into a datagridview in the Forms application if possible. Thank you for your help so far. my application is finding the files in the folder.

Comment: info is nothing but a class you can see with your 3 required property. just google how to bind a List into Datagridview. its so simple. @clerktech

Answer (score 1):

You will feel much less pain using LINQ to XML. The trick in this case is to take care of all the namespaces defined in the document. But that's not too hard with *XNamespace.Get* method and the *XName* concatenation operator overload.

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, string, string>> GetDocumentsData(string folderPath)
{
    var filingMessageNamespace = XNamespace.Get("urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CoreFilingMessage-4.0");
    var ncNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0");
    var ecfNamespace = XNamespace.Get("urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0");
    var jNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://niem.gov/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0");

    return Directory
        .GetFiles(folderPath, "XML*.xml")
        .Select(XDocument.Load)
        .SelectMany(
            file => 
                file.Descendants(filingMessageNamespace + "FilingLeadDocument")
                .Concat(file.Descendants(filingMessageNamespace + "FilingConnectedDocument")))
        .Select(
            documentNode =>
                Tuple.Create(
                    DateTime.Parse(documentNode.Element(ncNamespace + "DocumentReceivedDate").Element(ncNamespace + "DateTime").Value),
                    documentNode.Element(ncNamespace + "DocumentDescriptionText").Value.Trim(),
                    documentNode.Element(ecfNamespace + "DocumentMetadata").Element(jNamespace + "RegisterActionDescriptionText").Value.Trim()))
        .ToArray();
}
```

You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx) if you want to learn more. Just keep in mind that the whole API is much more intuitive than *XmlDocument's* DOM approach and works transparently with LINQ to objects.

Comment: what is "Tuple"? I created a class but VS2010 is requiring 3 arguments. Here is the complete error: "Error 1 Using the generic type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Tuple<T1,T2,T3>' requires 3 type arguments".

Comment: Tuple is a family of classes introduced in .Net 4.0. They reside in the System namespace. Non-generic Tuple provides static methods for generic Tuples' creation. In this case I use the generic Tuple<DateTime, string, string>, data of which can be read from, accordingly, Item1, Item2 and Item3.

Comment: I was building in 3.5 but it is all good. I will educate myself on this. Another error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple<System.DateTime,string,string>[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WindowsFormsApplication1.Tuple<System.DateTime,string,string>>'".

Comment: This is because of your own Tuple you've created. Delete it and this should compile.

Comment: you are awesome!!! hopefully last time I bother you. What is the best method to put this into a datagridview to displaying all these fields?

Comment: Look [here](https://gist.github.com/galenus/7127213) for a full example of how to solve your problem. But it is better you create a new question for each thing, searching the site for existing answers before that.

Comment: thank you. I learned a lot and a better method of doing this because this information will continue to grow. All your help is much appreciated.